# how to override default value of context with user setting?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm just tried to implement `Context` API of react into my `React Native` but i have a problem to override default value of my theme into `user setting` theme value

i have a file called `ThemeContext.js` as below:

```
const defaultColor = {
  backgroundColor:ListColor.teal_200,
  //another color
}

const defaultStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  containerCenter:{
    flex:1,
    alignItems:'center',
    backgroundColor:defaultColor.backgroundColor
  },
  //another styling
})

export const Theme = (userColors = {}, userStyles = {})=> {
  const mergedColors = {
    ...defaultColor,
    ...userColors
  }

  const mergedStyles = {
    ...defaultStyles,
    ...userStyles
  }

  return{
    colors:mergedColors,
    styles:mergedStyles
  }
}

export const ThemeContext = createContext({
  Theme:Theme(),
})

export const ProviderTheme = ThemeContext.Provider
export const ConsumerTheme = ThemeContext.Consumer
```

and i used it on my `ThemeProvider.js` as below:

```
export default class ThemeProvider extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      Theme:Theme()
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ProviderTheme value={this.state}>
        <ConsumerTheme>{Theme=>this.props.children}</ConsumerTheme>
      </ProviderTheme>
    );
  }
}
```

I have put my `ThemeProvider` on Top-Level of my project (`App.js`), and i used it on my child component let say `Home.js`. But i have a problem to change the default value if i need a custom style in my component, I have tried this but the value isn't change:

```
//imported

const myColor={
  backgroundColor:'red'
}

Theme(myColor);

export default class Home extends React.Component{
  static contextType = ThemeContext;

  render() {
    const {Theme} = this.context
    console.log(Theme)
    //backgroundColor is not change into 'red'
    return(
      <View style={[Theme.styles.containerCenter]}>
        <Text>Sample</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

did i doing something wrong? anyone can help me how to fix it?